# Set resources with different expression in Arena Simulation

Tags: arena-simulation

I need to create a model with two servers (resources) at billing station. Both have different service rates and hence each has a different delay expression (time to "process" the order) one has UNIF(mean,std dev) and the other one has EXP(lambda).

How do I assign the expressions in Arena model? It prompts only for one common expression to the servers in a process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your service time an attribute of the entities with an assign. When you edit the process modules (or delay modules) make the time not expression based, but instead attribute-based.